# Does someone not fasting still try their best?

Tags: halacha, fast-days, eating

If someone is exempt from fasting on a minor fast day, with the example that I have in mind being a nursing woman, is there any concept that they should still fast as much as possible, or do we say that once the fast is broken it is broken?

Does it make a difference if they have not broken their fast yet?  I.e. if someone woke up and has not yet eaten, is there any reason for them to push off breakfast so that they have gone longer without breaking their fast?

Comment: Not a dupe of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13026?rq=1 as this asks about exemption, not accidental violation.

Comment: There may be differences on different fasts and differences depending on each individual. This question is one that should be asked of ones Rabbi.

Comment: What @GershonGold said. Mostly because it depends on _why_ the person is not fasting -- if "trying their hardest" will cause problems along the lines of why they're not fasting in the first place, then absolutely not. If they could get away with it, then maybe....CYLOR

Comment: http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A0_%D7%90#.D7.90.D7.9C.D7.90_.D7.A9.D7.A0.D7.94.D7.92.D7.95_.D7.9C.D7.94.D7.97.D7.9E.D7.99.D7.A8

Comment: @GershonGold I never understand why some questions get this response and others don't.  We have a halacha question tag, and my question never refers to myself, nor is it for myself.  Are there not general rules that can be discussed for such a halacha?

Comment: @Shokhet ping ^^^

Comment: @YEZ I wasn't trying to give you advice, nor was I trying to answer the question (cuz I left a comment, not an answer;) .....but, I figured I'd leave what I know as fact (from asking reputable rabbis) here as a comment, for other people's benefit, along with a CYLOR warning for people who might take what is written here as practical advice

Answer (score 2):

As a general idea the Mishna Brurah writes that the idea of fasts is to bring one to do tshuva not to just fast and go on like a regular day,it is like taking the tafel instead of the ikar. If a mother needs to nurse then she should eat what she needs. If one is allowed to eat it means just that but to eat fancy things or sweets that are not necessary does not fit with the spirit of the day.