Would a siyum the night before the fast of the first born count?
There is a custom to make a siyum the day of Erev Pesach so that the first borns who participate will not have to fast.
I have always seen that siyum done on the day itself. I would like to know if a siyum made the night before (ie the night of the 14th of Nissan) would count so that a bechor who participated would not have to fast on the subsequent day of the 14th.

Why would it help to eat before the fast begins?

"There is a custom to make a siyum the day of Erev Pesach so that the first borns who participate will not have to fast." This is incorrect. There is a custom that first borns seek out a Seudat Mitzva so that they have an excuse to not fast. If for example there is a bris that day at shul then no one bothers to make a siyum also.

@DoubleAA the simcha removes the obligation to fast that day. why should it matter if the obligation is removed in the night or the day?

Well that's an assumption.

The simcha allows him to eat because the mitzva of eating overrides the minhag to fast. Does that mean he'd be allowed to eat once the seuda is over?

One way to look at would be: The Siyum (or Bris or other Seudas Mitzvah) enables breaking the fast, and once a fast is broken (exception: Yom Kippur) there is no more reason to fast. But if one eats at a Seudas Mitzvah at night for a fast that starts in the morning, one could argue that the since they have not "broken" the fast (since it had not started yet) they could, and should, fast the whole daytime because it can still be a complete fast.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Not just Yom Kippur https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13028/759

@DoubleAA Interesting. I have heard different Psak in some situations - I suspect it may depend on whether it is accidental (as in the linked post - e.g., you woke up in the morning and forgot it was a fast day) vs. permitted and deliberate (e.g., a sick person - who might only need to eat/drink once during the day but would benefit from eating/drinking again later in the day).

R. Elhanan Naftali Printz (Abhnei Derekh, vol. 14, p. 240) explores this topic as it relates to a physician that will be on duty:


A physician who has a shift that starts on the night of bediqath
hames, may he before his shift starts (on the night of the 14th) make
a siyum on a tractate and thereby be exempt from Ta'anith Bekhoroth,
or is he obligated to fast (since in the course of his shift it is
reasonable to expect that he will not be able to make a siyum)?
In the Shu"T Hawoth Yair (70) he writes that there is a din se'udath
miswah on the day after a siyum masekheth, and the basis for his
opinion is the se'udah that King Solomon made after Hanukath Beth
ha-Miqdash (when he made a se'udah for 7 days), see there. In the
Shu"T Minhath Yishaq (8, 45) he expresses doubt over whether bekhorim
can make a siyum on the night of the 14th of Nissan (and see there
where he raises difficulties against the Hawoth Yair), and his opinion
is that seemingly a siyum cannot be done at the night, see there.
In the pamphlet be-Yom Hathunatho (R. M. Gross, in Sha'ar Maamarim) he
draws on the sefer Shomer Emeth (Hilkhoth Lulabh ch. 669) a hint
favoring the notion of a se'udah during the day that is after a siyum,
one of the sources for a siyum masekheth is from the fact that the
15th of Abh was rendered a day of joy and the Rashbam explains that on
that day they completed a great miswah, "that he who increases"
explains the Rashbam is one who adds from the night to a different
day, thereby increases the days of his life, etc. Which is to say that
it shows that the completion of the 'abhodah [of cutting the wood for
the mizbeah] was on the 14th, and by the 15th they were no longer
cutting, the simhah was on the 15th, from here is a hint favoring the
position of the Hawoth Yair the also on the day after a siyum there is
a concept of se'udath miswah.
In the Shu"T Maharam Brisk (1, 133) he seeks to differentiate between
one who is mesayem himself from those that were merely with him at the
time of the se'udah. Which is to say that the mesayem himself when he
completes the miswah he can rejoice at any moment and time of that day
in which he completed the miswah and so anyway he can make the siyum
at night. But those that didn't learn (rather they just joined
together for the se'udah), they can join in on his joy in the
happiness of Torah (i.e. in the se'udah they are making to honor the
completion of Torah and miswah) but they cannot thereby exempt
themselves from the obligation of Ta'anith Bekhoroth the next day. And
similarly is brought down in the Shu"T Shebhet ha-Qehati (4, 45) and
in the sefer Yesode Yeshurun (6, p. 50).
And I saw that it was written in the Shu"T wa-Yebharekh Dawid (1, 24)
that if one completes a masekheth at night, he does not say Tahanun
the next day. And it proves that a siyum at night exempts the day. And
similarly is brought in the sefer Abhodath Efraim (Ch. 12, Hilkhoth
Tahanun) and the author of the Shebhet ha-Qehati also notes this.
The sefer Yuma Tabha le-Rabanan (6, 16) writes concerning this "if one
completes a masekheth on the night of the 14th, there are those that
say he is exempt from the fast during the following day and it even
exempts those that partner together with him for the [se'udah of the]
siyum, and there are those that disagree, at a time of pressing need
the one who is mesayem himself is exempt but not those that partner
with him", and similarly is written in the Nit'ei Gabhriel (Pesah,
sec. 2 43, 15). And see also in the sefer MiBeth Lewi (Pisqe Halakhoth
mi-Beth Midrashi shel Shebhet ha-Lewi, ch. 76 note 2).
The law that emerges: A physician that has a shift that begins during
the night of bediqath hames may before his shift begins (on the night
of the 14th) make a siyum masekheth and thereby be exempted from
Ta'anith Bekhoroth (however he is not able to thereby exempt others).


excellent source, thank you

@rikitikitembo my pleasure glad to be of assistance... of course this all comes from the side that sees this fast as obligatory.. there are sources on the other side that maintain that this custom of fasting on 'erebh Pesah is mistaken and in fact forbidden (e.g. R. Yosef Qafih) and for whom this discussion would therefore be moot.

A bris on fast day generally has the seudat mitzva at night after the fast on the next day so it seems clear that if need be a seudat mitzva can be delayed somewhat. The point missing from all this is whether the meal the next day is still a seudat mitzva if you've completely forgotten what happened the night before and are eating the same cheerios as usual alone in your hospital break room. Some donuts and OJ in the morning with guys at shul isn't a fancy seudat mitzva but it's deliberate and apparent that it's for a reason.
